# How to execute my own script after every webpack's auto build in watch mode of vue-cli 3.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack

### My current situation

Now I am using vue-cli@3.9.2. For some reason, I need to watch file change of my source code to run webpack's build, with `vue-cli-service build --watch`.

### My current solution

Currently, I run another Node.js process to watch file change, of webpack's bundle. I really suffered from this terrible development experience.

### Compare with vue-cli 2.x

When I used vue-cli 2.x, I actually run `webpack()`, one native API of webpack, in `build/build.js`, so I could use `webpack().watch()` instead to run build and pass my own script as callback function. However in vue-cli 3.x, there's no way and no need to approach the webpack's native API, within my knowledge.

### Summary

I wish to run my own script after webpack's every auto build, though I could not find any guidance in vue-cli's official document.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From my understanding - you have a Webpack plugin use case. Just like for example [webpack-build-notifier](https://github.com/RoccoC/webpack-build-notifier) sends a notification after a rebuild.

I am not a Webpack plugin author, but this is already working for me:

```js
// vue.config.js
const ArbitraryCodeAfterReload = function(cb) {
  this.apply = function(compiler) {
    if (compiler.hooks && compiler.hooks.done) {
      compiler.hooks.done.tap('webpack-arbitrary-code', cb);
    }
  };
};

const myCallback = function() {
  console.log('Implementing alien intelligence');
};

const plugins = [];
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
if (isDev) {
  plugins.push(new ArbitraryCodeAfterReload(myCallback));
}

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins
  }
};
```

If this is not the right compilation step - the Webpack [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/plugins/) should somewhere have the right `hook` for your use case.

Maybe there is already a plugin available which already does what you need...

Comment: This is beyond my knowledge, I haven't wrote any webpack plugin. However, if I can't find any existing solution, I will try. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! However, it is weird that create a plugin just for webpack's hook.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can help you. This is just an example. You only need to use `&&`

```
npm run start && npm run build
```

So after the npm run start script execute your npm run build script will run after the first one

Update you can use this package [webpack-shell-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shell-plugin)

```
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');

new WebpackShellPlugin({
  onBuildStart: [''],
  onBuildEnd: ['']
})
```

Comment: when in watch mode, it won't end the first command, so the second command will never be executed.

Comment: do you have any webpack config file?

Comment: The webpack config is managed and built by vue-cli, I can edit it through vue-cli, and the final built config is very complecated.

Comment: that will be difficult for me since I cant modify the webpack config file.  But im using webpack shell command to solve this issue

Comment: @Array-Huang check my answer again. Thanks

Comment: It looks like something I want, but the last version was published 3 years ago. I'm worried about this won't work. But I will try later. Thanks!